# Compiling QtAV Library for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

for more than a week now i am trying to build QtAV 1.12.0 for Android from a Windows 10 Machine, following these instructions:

https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/wiki/Build-QtAV

I am using

- QtAV 1.12.0 from git.
- Qt 5.12.4 (tried 5.14.0 but refering to https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/issues/1262 there are different/new issues)
- JDK 1.8.0
- NDK 19.2 (tried 21.1 as well)
- Android SDK 26.1.1
- ffmpeg dependencies: ffmpeg-3.1.4-anrdoid-armv7a-clang from here:
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtav/files/depends/FFmpeg/android/
- i tried different android ffmpeg dependencies from that page, all resulting in the same (or even earlier) errors.
- Copied ffmpeg dependencies (/lib, /include, /share, ...) to the ..\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7 Folder
- Copied ffmpeg dependencies to the Project root dir and added the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS to qtav.pro file (and later even to .qmake.conf)

Android Device setup is fine except for the OpenSSL part. I guess this is not relevant, right? (I can deploy my applications to my android phone anyway.)

I am using Qt Creator 4.12.3 to build and i am facing errors. The build process aborts at 108 warnings and 2 errors:

error: cannot find -lass
clang++.exe:-1: Fehler: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

but in the /config.log way earlier errors occur, which i think may cascade down to the result above:

```
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libavresample.so -o libavresample.so main.obj  -lavresample -LC:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/lib  -LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++.so.16 -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc 
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -lavresample
> clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:71: libavresample.so] Error 1
test avresample FAILED
executing config test avfilter
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avfilter && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/avfilter
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avfilter && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -mthumb -Oz -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\avfilter -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\avfilter\main.cpp
> del libavfilter.so
> C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avfilter\libavfilter.so konnte nicht gefunden werden
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libavfilter.so -o libavfilter.so main.obj  -lavfilter -LC:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/lib  -LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++.so.16 -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc 
test avfilter succeeded
executing config test avdevice
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avdevice && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/avdevice
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avdevice && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -mthumb -Oz -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\avdevice -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\avdevice\main.cpp
> del libavdevice.so
> C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\avdevice\libavdevice.so konnte nicht gefunden werden
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libavdevice.so -o libavdevice.so main.obj  -lavdevice -LC:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/lib  -LC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++.so.16 -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc 
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: cannot find -lavdevice
> clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:71: libavdevice.so] Error 1
test avdevice FAILED
executing config test sse4_1
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\sse4_1 && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/sse4_1
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\sse4_1 && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -msse4.1 -g -g -marm -O0 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC  -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\sse4_1 -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o sse4_1.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\sse4_1\sse4_1.cpp
> clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.1' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
> In file included from C:\QtAV\config.tests\sse4_1\sse4_1.cpp:42:
> In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\smmintrin.h:27:
> In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\tmmintrin.h:27:
> In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\pmmintrin.h:27:
> In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\emmintrin.h:27:
> In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\xmmintrin.h:27:
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
>     __builtin_ia32_emms();
>     ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
>     __builtin_ia32_emms();
>                         ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
>     return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
>            ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:430:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsb'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:453:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsw'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
>                   ^
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\8.0.2\include\mmintrin.h:475:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddusb'
>     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
>                   ^
> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
> 20 errors generated.
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:438: sse4_1.obj] Error 1
test sse4_1 FAILED
executing config test openal
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\openal && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/openal
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\openal && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -O2 -O2 -mthumb  -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\openal -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\openal\main.cpp
> del libopenal.a
> C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\openal\libopenal.a konnte nicht gefunden werden
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar cqs libopenal.a main.obj
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib libopenal.a
test openal succeeded
executing config test libass
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\libass && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/libass
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\libass && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -O2 -O2 -mthumb  -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\libass -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\libass\main.cpp
> del liblibass.a
> C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\libass\liblibass.a konnte nicht gefunden werden
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar cqs liblibass.a main.obj
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib liblibass.a
test libass succeeded
executing config test uchardet
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\uchardet && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/uchardet
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\uchardet && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -mthumb -Oz -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC  -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\uchardet -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\uchardet\main.cpp
> C:\QtAV\config.tests\uchardet\main.cpp:21:10: fatal error: 'uchardet/uchardet.h' file not found
> #include 
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:451: main.obj] Error 1
test uchardet FAILED
executing config test libcedarv
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\libcedarv && C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe  -spec C:/Qt/Qt5.12.4/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" C:/QtAV/config.tests/libcedarv
+ cd /d C:\build-QtAV-USERDEF_Android\config.tests\libcedarv && set MAKEFLAGS=& mingw32-make
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/android/support/include -isystem C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove -mthumb -Oz -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC  -IC:\QtAV\config.tests\libcedarv -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\include -IC:\QtAV\contrib\dxsdk -IC:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\5.12.4\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-clang -o main.obj C:\QtAV\config.tests\libcedarv\main.cpp
> C:\QtAV\config.tests\libcedarv\main.cpp:21:10: fatal error: 'libcedarv/libcedarv.h' file not found
> #include 
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:451: main.obj] Error 1
test libcedarv FAILED
```

I am not tied to a specific SDK / NDK / Qt / QtAV Version.

I successfully built QtAV for MSVC2017 x32 and x64 so i assume it must have something to do with the ffmpeg dependecies or the whole JDK/SDK/NDK setup. Anyone has a clue where i am going wrong here?

Since the building starts and runs for a while i think that the provided depencencies are found by the compiler/linker but may be incomplete?

As a note: AFAIK the libass stuff is required for displaying subtitles in videos. I do not need that feature (i want to stream rstp live streams from cameras). Disabling modules as a workaround, e.g. with a CONFIG -= switch, is a welcome solution as well and a try worth.

What i am not sure about is the Kit/sysroot line. Is there anything required here? It is empty by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly answering your question but it may still help you to avoid it maybe:

QtAV library has been rewritten from scratch by its developer under the new project "MDK-SDK" (link below).

https://github.com/wang-bin/mdk-sdk

Because these libraries are very complicated to build with many dependencies, he provides binaries for most platforms as nightly build.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mdk-sdk/files/nightly/

NOTE: The license is not free from commercial apps, (but is affordable) and the library works well with good performance.

Comment: Hey Alexandre, thanks for the reply! Thats the explanation why that awesome project QtAV is not continued since 2017. I will check it out.